# Grails include custom script

Tags: grails, include

I have two script in my grails application, how can I need a target of a script into another one, how can I do it?

I tried doing:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("FirstScript")
```

but grails throws an Exception...I tried also with:

```
includeTargets << FirstScript
```

but this one says that grails can't find the class...
How can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to shift in a file handle to the script:

```
includeTargets << new File("${basedir}/scripts/_FirstScript.groovy)
```